# Error in a loop performing SGD with a pytorch model

Tags: model, pytorch, unpack, dataloader, sgd

within a function used to perform stochastic gradient descent, I have this loop over all batches and over all input-output pair within a batch:

```
train_points_loader = DataLoader(train_points, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(train_points_loader):
  o.zero_grad() # setting gradient to zeros    
  pred = model(X) # get predictions through forward pass
  loss = l(pred, y) # compute the loss

  loss.backward() # backward propagation        
    
  o.step() # update the gradient to new gradients
```

And I am using this following pytorch model:

```
 model = nn.Sequential( 
 nn.Flatten(), 
 nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_layers[0]),
 nn.ReLU(),
 nn.Linear(hidden_layers[0], hidden_layers[1]),
 nn.ReLU(),
 nn.Linear(hidden_layers[1], output_size)
 )
```

When I run the loop which is inside a function, the error is:

```
  <ipython-input-24-a177ccf6125b> in train_loop(train_data_loader, 
  model, epochs, learning_rate, optimizer, loss)
  21     running_accuracy = 0.
  22     # loop over all batches and over all input-output pair within a 
  batch
  ---> 23     for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(train_data_loader):
  24 
  25         o.zero_grad() # setting gradient to zeros

  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: please post the full error traceback, not just the error message. its hard to understand which line is causing the error.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited my question with the full error

Comment: What does the `__getitem__` method of your dataset return?